# RoR: "rails server" Lingering Load?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to RoR, and am building a few beginner's projects - but am unfamiliar with the error processing on RoR.  For instance, I am working on this [project right here](http://rubysource.com/building-your-first-rails-application-models/), even though the site I found it through warned it had a few errors (if you know of a program that shortens urls based on a domain you own, that has NO errors, let me know and I'll use it).  The problem I'm having is on the step:

```
rails server
```

It produces the result that the writer shows, then brings up a SECURITY WARNING.  Underneath the security warning it has three timestamps with INFO WEBBrick and INFO ruby.  However, an hour later, it's still here - and it hasn't brought the application back to the original location of the code (ie: C:\Location).

Is this an error?  Or is it supposed to load?  I ask because from the article it seems like I could just move on to the next step (after thirty minutes I hit ENTER just to see what happens, but no response), but - unless I open up a new command prompt - I don't see that happening.

Comment: What do you believe *should* be happening? Are you making any requests?

Comment: Dave, thanks.  The article seems to imply that I can move on to the next step.  Unless I load a new command prompt, I can't (unless loading the server takes four hours or something).  The trouble with being new to something is that I can't decipher if this is an error or whether the article forgot to mention - "Oh by the way, this won't allow you to continue coding, so you'll need to open up a new command prompt window."

Comment: The server is waiting for a request. You can always open up a new command prompt. Hit Control-C to stop the server, or use a new window. Note that sometimes you'll *need* to restart the server.

Comment: Thanks Dave; put that as an answer and I'll mark it.  That was exactly what I was wondering; sorry for the n00b Q.

Comment: Meh--if you don't know something, you don't know something--it's not a character flaw. Most tutorials assume some level of comfort with *something*, not always a valid assumption. My advice would be to not be scared to just try something; it's relatively rare it'd be truly damaging. (But you back up your system, right? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you made any requests?

After the Rails server starts, it will sit "forever" waiting to service client requests (e.g., from a browser). Under Windows, that command prompt won't be useful until the server is shut down, e.g., with a <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>.

You can either open a new command window, as you've done, or shut the server down and use the same window. It's worth nothing that sometimes you'll *need* to restart the server, much of the time you won't. Figuring out when, and under what circumstances, is deterministic, but occasionally confusing.

Comment: +1 Yup, that window and its process is now tied up running the rails server and responding to requests.  Open another terminal window to do more command line stuff.

Comment: Again, highly appreciate the answer Dave.